# Dining Philosophers in C memory leaks

Tags: c, memory, semaphore

i am trying to implement Dining Philosophers in C  using Resource hierarchy solution. when i am using valgrind everything goes fine. Unfortunately when i done this using console im getting random seqfaults. One time my program will be succesful,one time it will broke on the beginning. I would be grateful if anybody could point where i did mistake and why it's 100% succesfull.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_PHILOSPHERS 5

sem_t forks[NUM_PHILOSPHERS];
void *philosopher(void *param){
    printf("Thread created!");
    int *id = (int *)param;
    int L = 0;
    sem_t* Myforks[2];
    int par = *id;
    if(par == 4){
        Myforks[0]  = &forks[4];
        Myforks[1]  = &forks[0];
    }else{
        Myforks[0]  = &forks[par];
        Myforks[1]  = &forks[par+1];
    }
    while(L!=5){    
        printf("Eat spaghetti!",*id);
        sem_wait(Myforks[0]);
        sem_wait(Myforks[1]);
        //.....
        printf("EAT spaghetti!",*id);
        sem_post(Myforks[1]);
        sem_post(Myforks[0]);
        L=L+1;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    int i;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_PHILOSPHERS];

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSPHERS; i++)
        sem_init(&forks[i], 0, 1);
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSPHERS; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, philosopher, (void *)&i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i suppose it has nothing to do with memory leaks.

Comment: main() just before the return() statement, needs to wait for each of the threads to exit, perhaps via pthread_join()

Comment: the code in the philosopher function, that is handling the the semaphores could be made much simpler by making use of the '%' modulo operator, so no need for the if/else code blocks

Comment: the use of 'forks is invalid as a philosopher can eat with a single fork.  The philosopher problem is normally implemented with chop sticks, one chop stick between each philosopher.  Where the philosopher needs two chop sticks to be able to eat.  Normally the philosopher is expected to eat/think for several cycles.  The current code is failing the cycle count and the printf statements are very confusing.  Have you actually read/understand the dining philosopher problem.  here is a link that discusses the details of the problem, using C++ classes, but it is easy to convert to C

Comment: oops, forgot the link: <http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/MUTEX/TM-example-philos-1.html>

Comment: thank u all. Now this program is working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i;

...

for(i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSPHERS; i++) 
  pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, philosopher, (void *)&i);
                                                         ^^
```

Passing a pointer to a local variable isn't going to work. You're passing the same address to all of the threads, so there's an inherent race condition. You point them a pointer to `i` and them almost immediately you increment `i`. What value will they read when they access `*param`? Who knows!

You'll want to create an array with `NUM_PHILOSPHERS` (sic) slots in it and pass a different address to each thread. You'll also want to make sure that array isn't destroyed when `main()` exits—i.e., make the array global or static, not local.